# Rendering rectangles through other rectangles

Tags: processing

For some reason when I draw over another rectangle in my current processing sketch, it draws over all other rectangle fills, but does not appear to draw over other rectangle strokes. when I make another sketch this problem doesn't persist, but it happens consistently in this sketch.

**Overlapping rectangles picture**

[[image: Overlapping rectangles picture]]

**Example**

Here's a simplified example which seems to recreate the issue

```
void setup(){
  size(1000, 600 , P3D);
  surface.setResizable(true);
  //frameRate(120);
}


void draw(){
  if(width < 100)
    size(100,height,P3D);
  if(height < 100)
    size(width,100,P3D);

  fill(10);
  stroke(10);
  strokeWeight(10);
  rect(100,100,100,100);

  fill(255);
  stroke(100);
  strokeWeight(10);
  rect(0,0,300,300);
}
```

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve]?

Comment: Can you please add the code?

Comment: I'm currently working on making a minimal example. It's tough though, i'm having a hard time reproducing the error independently in a smaller example.

Comment: I posted a small example which recreates a similar issue on my system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you set size with the "P3D" argument. P3D is a 3D rendering mode. This result is likely due to some eccentricity of rendering the 2D rect() function in a 3D space.

Comment: also, FYI, size should not be used outside of the setup function. use surface.setsize() instead.